# Any database-driven differential backup software?

Tags: backup

The idea is to take differential backups (new files and folders since last backup), but with no old backups at hand instead by comparing the source directory against a database containing information of last backed up state.

Any suggestions? Preferably windows software.

No DIFFERENTIAL-BACKUP tag existed and I was not able to create it.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually all backup software works like that...Even Windows' own builtin backup tool.
Otherwise how do you imagine backups to tape happen, especially when tapes are sent offsite.
Any good backup software keeps its own internal db to know what files changed since the last backup.